# Variables equality

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm unsure why example 1 don't give the same result as example 2.

Example 1:

```
var a = [1,6,2,4];
var b = [];
function minT(data){
    var d = [];
    d = data;
      d.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
      return d;
};

b = minT(a)

console.log("b =" +  b);
console.log("a =" +  a);
```

Results:

```
 b =1,2,4,6    
 a =1,2,4,6
```

Example2:

```
var a = [1,6,2,4];
var b = [];
function minT(data){
    var d = [];
    d = data.slice(0,10);
      d.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
      return d;
};

b = minT(a)

console.log("b =" +  b);
console.log("a =" +  a);
```

Results:

```
b = 1,2,4,6     
a = 1,6,2,4
```

Why does example 1 affect array a?
How can I write a function `minT` that does not affect array a. (without a slice inside the function)?

Comment: Erm... because you're modifying the array? `.slice(0)` is the standard quick way to do a shallow copy on an array specifically to prevent this from happening.

Comment: You can simplify this problem; Say `var a = ['fizz'], b, foo;` then consider `foo = a; foo[0] = 'buzz'; b = foo;` vs `foo = a.slice(0); foo[0] = 'buzz'; b = foo;` then finally look at what you have as `a` and `b` --- hint in the first `foo === a`, in the second `foo !== a`

Comment: Thanks .slice(0) it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your first attempt sorts your `a` array also is because `d = data;` just copies the object reference, so both variables are pointing to the same location in memory.

When you do `d = data.slice(0,10);`, you're assigning the result of the `slice` operation to the `d` variable, which is a different object in memory than the `data` variable is pointing to.

Check out [this book excerpt](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm) on the differences between value vs reference.

Answer (score 0):

In example 1:

You have written `d=data`. It means that d is pointing to the element `data`. You have not just copied the values.

Example 2:

You have written `d=data.slice(0,10)`. It actually copies the element of data rather than copying the address of `data`.

Now, to write the function minT without affecting `data`, and without using function `data.slice()`, you just need to replace the line `data.slice()` with your own simple code to copy element of one array to another.

Here's what I've done :

```
function minT(data){
var d = [];
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    d[i]=data[i];
  d.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  return d;
};
```

Comment: ok. I didn't know about the reference vs value copy. i will stick with .slice(0) thanks

Comment: Not an issue. I just gave you another option.